# Simplest code working when Activity calls Fragment but not when it calls ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Works when `extends Fragment` is used, but not with `ListFragment`.

Main Activity:

```
public class FagTabHostMain extends FragmentActivity {
    FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_fag_tab_host_main);

            mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("more").setIndicator("More"),
                    More.class, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Works with below:

```
public class More extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.more, null);
        return view;
    }
}
```

But not with:

```
public class More extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.more, null);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does mean "not working". Can you please post the stack trace to see what the error is. A common error is to have the wrong name in the list to extend a ListFragment.

Comment: Also post your 'more' layout please.

Comment: Do you have a listview in your R.layout.activity_fag_tab_host_main?  Post the xml for that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `R.layout.more` has to be a `ListView` with `android:id="@android:id/list"` tag, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```